# Upgraded Android Studio to Flamingo, now won't build my projects

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I do not enjoy the process of updating IDE's as there is more often than not, some kind of issue.

I have recently upgraded Android Studio to Flamingo, and have had a sore head ever since. Mostly around Gradle. I have attempted search for solutions to work through each issue one by one, but I fear that the more things I change, the further I am getting from what will solve it, and to undo all my changes will be a bigger nightmare. Most of the solutions are for older versions of Android Studio.

I am using Android Studio to build a Flutter project.

In my build.gradle, I have so far added / changed:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'

android {
  namespace 'com.mydomain.myproject'
}
```

in my gradle-wrapper.properties, I have set...

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1.1-all.zip

in gradle.properties, I have commented the line... org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

I have installed JAVA jdk-20 after the build was complaining I was using 1.8 (which was jre rather than jdk)

but, I am still getting issues and I have run out of ideas and searches to make this a fix.

Right now, I have the problem...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\david\FlutterProjects\myproject\android\build.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_b8x5roukd43x6hkz1qkzv9s9h$_run_closure1@1fe6e8eb] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I am on a Windows 11 machine if that is any help.

Have I gone too far in the changes I have made?

How do I get this to build now? Everything worked fine before I ungraded the IDE.

I guess I will have these same issues when I also set it up on my Macbook.

**EDIT**:

It seems I put the android namespace into the wrong build.gradle. I had put it in android\build.gradle when it should be in app\build.gradle.

However, still having issues. The error now is:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
      > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [C:\Users\david\FlutterProjects\myproject\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustrating as it was, I have made quite a bit of progress, though right now, I have issues with plugin versions. That is probably going to be easier to resolve.

The answer to fixing the gradle issue was found https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

There are a number of things to look out for. In my case, I made changes as pointed out in Step 3 and Step 5. This allowed my build to get much further, and now it is showing issues with my plugins.